# UITableView won't scroll on iPad, but does on iPhone

Tags: xcode, uitableview

If I turn my iPad to landscape a couple of row of table view (and the footer) are just off the bottom of the screen  although it fits in portrait.

My problem is that when I use my finger to "pull" view port up to see the material off the bottom I can see it while I keep my finger in place, but when I remove the finger, the viewport drops down again and the material at the bottom disappears.

Same code scrolls fine on iPhone (fonts are too big and so on but that is a different issue)

What am I doing wrong?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

As for what exactly your doing wrong... we can't see your code so we can't tell you. But shed some light on what is happening.

A `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` and how far you can scroll is based on the size view (think `frame`) compared to the size(`CGSize`) of the content(`contentSize`) of the `UIScrollView`. If the 'frame' is bigger than the `contentSize` then no scrolling is needed, but if the content is larger, then you can scroll by the difference between the two.

In short, the `contentSize` of your `UITableView` is incorrect. This can be caused numerous ways, including auto-resizing on device rotations, dynamically changing table/footer heights without updating the table, etc.

Comment: Very helpful thanks.  I have experimented with the frame size and content size and I _think_ I understand it better now.  You pointed me in the right direction, which was what I was after.